# JAR vs EXE when deploying a Java application

Tags: jar, exe

I am deploying a Java application for Windows users and I am considering what file format to use. What is the difference between a jar file and a exe file?

I know that the jar file is a container of java class files and exe is an executable file, but is there any other differences? Security (is my code "safer" in an exe?)? Is there any performance differences?

Thanks!

Comment: No data to suggest that the choice should be based on security or performance. A JAR will be more portable; not restricted to Windows.

Answer (score 0):

.jar file needs the JRE installed on the system in order to run. The .exe file has the JRE packaged into it so it can run on windows w/o a JRE installed.